# How to edit save game file?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to add tons of gold to my second (pure mage) skyrim game. Which is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about editing save files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually this is easy. All you'll need is

- A USB stick
- A program called Horizon
- Skyrim on PC

Format the USB stick on your 360, copy your Skyrim save over to the USB stick.

Install Horizon onto you PC, and insert the USB stick. Locate the save file for Skyrim in Horizon. Extract then save the file into you PC's Skyrim saves folder. When you've saved it, relocate the file and change the extension to `.ess`.

Load Skyrim and your save should work. Enter the console and type the money cheat; save when you have enough. Load the file in Horizon, resign and rehash it, and save the file back onto your USB stick. Put the USB stick back into the Xbox, copy the save file over, and you're done.

Answer (score 5):

Many XBox Skyrim players have PCs that can install and launch Skyrim successfully, although it is not good enough to actually play on. Many people have friends who have PC version of Skyrim.

If that's the case, you can copy the XBox save file to a USB key, open it up on a PC, and modify the save file through console commands, and transfer it back to XBox.

There should be no mods running on the PC, and version and DLC should match.

Answer (score 2):

As an answer to another question stated:

> Console commands are, in fact, PC only: PS3 and Xbox 360 owners do not get access to the console

So what your trying do seems next to impossible (I assume you wanted  to do this though hacking)

If you intend to make money in Skyrim the legitimate I suggest looking here

[How do I make money efficiently?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35800/how-do-i-make-money-efficiently)