# How can I make money quickly and easily?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make money efficiently?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35800/how-do-i-make-money-efficiently)

I have a good bit of gold now but I'm still trying to get more, and I need some quick and easy ways to earn more gold, besides chopping wood. And if it helps, I have Hearthfire and Dawnguard expansion packs.