# Where should I sell the Exquisite Sapphire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know the sapphire is worth 5000 and there is a way to have more than one. But where can I find the best merchant to sell to? The one in Riverwood has been patched (360) and cannot get more than 3000 from the vendor.

Was wondering if anyone knows a better way to get coin, speech is 100 and merchant has had 500 investment.

Comment: Is the issue getting gold?  There are much better ways to earn money in Skyrim than sell expensive loot.  You can [MAKE expensive loot instead](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35800/how-do-i-make-money-efficiently).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most [merchants in Skyrim](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Merchants) operate with chump change.  Yes, the `Investor` perk can marginally increase that, but the extra 500 G won't help all that much.

- The richest vendors in Skyrim are the Fences of the Thieves' Guild.  Without help from your Speech skill, a Fence can have 4000 G.  When you join the Thieves' Guild you'll quickly be introduced to your first Fence in the Ragged Flagon.  Shortly into the main Thieves' Guild quest line, you'll gain access to a 2nd Fence outside of Whiterun.  If you've been working "small jobs" for Delvin & Vex, you will have had the chance to recruit a Fence in every other walled city in Skyrim plus one in each Khajiit caravan.  When the Thieves' Guild is at full strength, you should have 9 Fences at your disposal.
- Wealthier Blacksmiths will generally come in 2nd place with up to 1000G.

  If you've got the `Master Trader` perk, you can add another 1000G to the starting purse of "participating locations".  As such, a "Master Trader" who "Invests" in a Prosperous Blacksmith, can expect them to have a whopping 2500G.  Save the Perks & stick with the Fences, unless you're playing a "virtuous" character who won't sink to joining the Thieves' Guild.
- Alternatively If you come to the shop with a heavy purse you can purchase some of the vendor's items to add a bit of weight to his/her purse in preparation for that valuable item you wish to unload.  Another variation of this trick is to sell to a merchant/trainer after you've purchased training.

FWIW:  I'm fond of Delvin's "Fishing" jobs.  Nothing like a good excuse to exercise that skill & improve things for the Guild...

Finally, How do you come by an Exquisite Sapphire without knowing about Fences?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best place to start is to get your Speech at 100. There are many ways of doing this from the [wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Speech)

1. Selling valuable items. I recommend you need Enchanting, Smithing, and Alchemy at 100 with all the perks and equip items that allow armor and potions to be stronger. This will allow you to make better valued items. Enchant apparel with 2 valuable enchantments, banish and paralysis. Then improve them, but only if it's armor. For potions, make a potion out of 3 ingredients. Then sell them to merchant. Now it's okay if they don't have enough money. The only thing you want to sell for money is the sapphire.
2. Ungrien Glitch. You must be before Patch 1.9 to do this. Talk to Ungrien in the Black Briar Meadery in Riften, ask about Maven, and use the persuade option. If he says he told the truth, bribe him until your Speech is at 25. You can do this again.

Now that's covered, you should spend on 2 perks:

- Investor, 80. Allows you to invest 500 gold. Before 1.9, investing in the Riverwood Trader adds 10,000 gold, making Lucan the richest merchant to sell the sapphire.
- Master Trader, 100. Merchants have an additional 1000 gold.

Now sell them to the fences in the Thieves' Guild [Or use Lucan before 1.9]. You must join them, complete the questline and the jobs so they will have 6000 gold.